# App says undefined post anytime I re-render errors on the same view

Tags: node.js, ejs

My app crashes anytime I redisplay the errors that my JOI validation gives me.
undefined post is all I get most of the time

This is my edit route handler

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  const result = error ? error.details : false;
  if (result.length > 0) {
    console.log(result);
    return res.render("admin/posts/edit", {
      errors: result
    });
  }
  res.send("post updated successfully");
});
```

This is my view

```
<h1>Edit Post</h1>

<form action="/admin/posts/<%=post._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="title" value="<%= post.title %>" />
  <input type="text" name="content" value="<%= post.content%>" />
  <button>Update post</button>
</form>
```

Comment: In your router you are using "put", but you probably want to use `router.post`. PUT and POST are two different HTTP request types.

Comment: thanks for the quick response

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: No it didn't realized I had to pass my post object to my router